# Alguém tem alguma ideia de como criar uma paginação com API RESTFULL em Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso e o JQUERY montar a paginação? Nem que seja algum tutorial. Já pesquisei em vários locais e todos dizem a mesma coisa de criar uma paginação no próprio laravel e trazer numa view. Só que o meu problema é trazer essa paginação com JQUERY em outro projeto, via API em JSON. Será que alguém poderia me explicar e dar um exemplo?

Comment: pode explicar melhor o que deseja?

Answer (score 0):

Eu creio que a resposta seja simples: Use o método `paginate` do Laravel.

Eu sempre uso isso nas minhas aplicações para fazer uma "paginação" (na verdade o que eu faço é um carregamento sobre demanda, usando a lógica da paginação do Laravel).

O que você precisa entender é que a paginação do laravel funciona passando o parâmetro `page` na query da url.

Ou seja:

```
Route::get('/api/users', function () {
     return User::paginate(10); // vai exibir de 10 em 10
});
```

No jQuery, você faz a sua lógica para parâmetro `page` ser adicionado dinamicamente:

```
var page = 1;

$.get('/api/users?page=' + page, function (response) {

});
```

Se você alterar o valor de `page`para `2`, você observaria que a "próxima página" seria carregadas com os dados que você precisa. Sabendo disso, você poderá aplicar a sua lógica livremente.

Geralmente, o que eu costumo fazer é uma implementação com Angular e Inifinite Scroll.

<sub>Tenho uma [biblioteca](https://github.com/wallacemaxters/ng-laravel-paginator) de onde você pode tirar mais exemplos.</sub>

Comment: Cara eu tentei fazer mas preciso que o page seja automático entendeu?

Comment: Vou colocar meu código na pergunta

Comment: Mas a lógica do page é você que vai implementar. Sua pergunta não está clara no sentido de como vai implementar.